# How can I escape a newline in .ps1 files?

Tags: powershell

I want to write a PowerShell script that includes a single command that is split over new lines, such as (the actual command I am trying to run is longer):

```
ssh \
   -L 8080:localhost:8080 \
   foo@bar.com
```

However the `\` doesn't escape the new line (neither does `/`).

Comment: You could try to use a backtick  but it has to be the last charachter on the line. For such a short line it's actually unnecessary to insert a line break and for native Powershell commands there are several ways to insert line breaks such as commata, semikola or the pipe.

Comment: The back just before the newline is the standard way.

Comment: The backtick is actually not a line continuation charachter but an escape charachter. But if the charachter it escapes is a line break it works just like a line continuation charachter. But if you accidently place a space after the backtick it does not work anymore like a line continuation charachter. That's why it is not a good style. Because it would be hard to debug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the backtick ( ` ), like this:

```
Write-Output `
    "Hello world!"
```

Comment: Backticks can seem handy, and I used to use them a lot to make more compact code, but they are generally discouraged for this purpose.  More info: [Bye Bye Backtick](https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/07/bye-bye-backtick-natural-line.html)